Ubuntu 22.04 with sysVinit
I am trying to setup a diskless cluster using pxe based on ubuntu 22.04 jammy. I can boot the client but its systemd fails to load many units and thus the system cannot be used (no user can login and no logs are written probably due to failure in systemd logging unit).
I had setup similar cluster many years ago based on debian 8 and at that time I decided to switch to sysvinit over systemd and the problems were solved. Now, I wanted to do the same and switch to sysvinit in ubuntu jammy but there is no sysvinit package. Is there any solution to replace systemd with sysvinit in jammy?

Sysvinit is old, obsolete, and hasvbeen replaced by systemd, a newer, better,  more powerful, more flexible, system. Trying to stick to SysVInit will make your life more difficult.

I am really stuck in the systemd problems! linux can boot from the client hdd as local hdd but no success in network boot. I checked and found that the filesystem is mounted correctly but the systemd cannot load many units and thus there is no gui, no ssh, no one can login and so the system is unusable.
